# How to Allocate Vector of Objects to the Heap

Tags: c++

I currently have a program that reads from a file.txt. The contents of this file contain athletes that competed in the Olympic Games for the long jump event.

The format is [First Name], [Last Name], [Nationality], [Distance]

This program will first verify whether the file can be read and output a console message "Data is loaded successfully" if it can.

Secondly it will prompt the user to enter a threshold distance (Ex: 7.7m) it will print out all athletes that have a distance > 7.7m.

My current program is capable of doing everything I want it do. However what I need help with is having 40 pointers (as there is 40 Athlete objects) that point to the objects in the Heap. After I would like to deallocate them in memory. Thanks in advance for the help!

**Test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include "Person.h"
#include "Athlete.h"
using namespace std;
using std::cerr;

//overload the operator << to be used for printing the Athlete  Objects
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Athlete& a) {
    out << a.getFirstName() << " " << a.getLastName() << " " << a.getNationality() << " " << a.getDistance() << "\n";
    return out;
}

vector<Athlete> athletesList;
vector<Athlete> readAthletesFromFile() {

    athletesList.reserve(40);
    fstream athlethesFile("file.txt");
    if (!athlethesFile) {
        cerr << "Could not open file\n";
        return athletesList;
    }
    string tmpFirstName;
    string tmpLastName;
    string tmpNationality;
    string tmpDoubleDistance;
    while (true) {
        athlethesFile >> tmpFirstName;
        athlethesFile >> tmpLastName;
        athlethesFile >> tmpNationality;
        athlethesFile >> tmpDoubleDistance;
        if (!athlethesFile) break;
        auto tmpDistance = stod(tmpDoubleDistance);
        athletesList.emplace_back(tmpFirstName, tmpLastName, tmpNationality, tmpDistance);

        //cout << athletesList.back();   

    }
    cout << "Data is loaded successfully." << "\n";
    return athletesList;
}

double validateUserInput() {
    double input;
    cout << "Please enter the distance threshold: ";
    cin >> input;

    if (input < 0) {
        throw runtime_error("Please enter positive integer.");
    };
    if (input < 6.55) {
        throw runtime_error("Number entered is too low!");
    }
    if (input > 8.11) {
        throw runtime_error("Number entered is too high!");
    }

    return input;
}

void printAthletes(vector<Athlete> athletesList, double maxDistance) {


    if (6.55 <= maxDistance <= 8.11) {
        cout << "The athletes that exceed " << maxDistance << " m " << "are: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < athletesList.size(); i++) {
            double tdist = athletesList[i].getDistance();
            if (tdist > maxDistance) {
                cout << athletesList[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    try{
        vector<Athlete> athletes {readAthletesFromFile()};
        double maxDistance {validateUserInput()};
        if (maxDistance >= 0)
            printAthletes(athletes, maxDistance);

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
        catch (exception & e) {
        cerr << "Exception occured: " << e.what() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**File.txt**

```
Aleksandr Menkov Russia 8.09
Aleksandr Petrov Russia 7.89
Alyn Camara Germany 7.72
Arsen Sargsyan Armenia 7.62
Boleslav Skhirtladze Georgia 7.26
Christian Reif Germany 7.92
Christopher Tomlinson Great_Britain 8.06
Damar Forbes Jamaica 7.79
Eusebio Caceres Spain 7.92
George Kitchens United_States 6.84
Godfrey Khotso-Mokoena South_Africa 8.02
Greg Rutherford Great_Britain 8.08
Henry Frayne Australia 7.95
Ignisious Gaisah Ghana 7.79
Li Jinzhe China 7.77
Lin Ching-Hsuan-Taipei China 7.38
Louis Tsatoumas Greece 7.53
Luis Rivera Mexico 7.42
Marcos Chuva Portugal 7.55
Marquise Goodwin United_States 8.11
Mauro-Vinicius da-Silva Brazil 8.11
Michel Torneus Sweden 8.03
Mitchell Watt Australia 7.99
Mohamed Fathalla-Difallah Egypt 7.08
Mohammad Arzandeh Iran 7.84
Ndiss Kaba-Badji Senegal 7.66
Povilas Mykolaitis Lithuania 7.61
Raymond Higgs Bahamas 7.76
Roman Novotny Czech-Republic 6.96
Salim Sdiri France 7.71
Sebastian Bayer Germany 7.92
Sergey Morgunov Russia 7.87
Stanley Gbagbeke Nigeria 7.59
Stepan Wagner Czech-Republic 7.5
Supanara Sukhasvasti Thailand 7.38
Tyrone Smith Bermuda 7.97
Vardan Pahlevanyan Armenia 6.55
Viktor Kuznyetsov Ukraine 7.5
Will Claye United_States 7.99
Zhang Xiaoyi China 7.25
```

Comment: `std::vector` already allocates objects in the heap. Why do you want to do that manually?

Comment: `vector<Athlete>` is a vector of `Athlete` *objects* not pointers. And the memory allocated internally by the vector is fully handled by the vector itself, and nothing you need to bother with.

Comment: What you have currently is better than what you're proposing.

Comment: Side note: `"Please enter positive integer"` – well, apparently 7.5 would be valid input, but that's certainly not an integer. Actually, I wouldn't care for that at all, as if 4.0 is too small, then -1.0 will be just as well, so one single check should be fine. Rather I'd add the valid range to the error output. By the way, upper limit is pretty low, too, wouldn't even allow for covering [*current* Olympic or world records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_jump)...

Answer (score 0):

You storing your data-objects in a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
vector<Athlete> athletes {readAthletesFromFile()};
```

so that will call the destructors of your objects and deallocate all the memory (that the same [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) allocated) for you. You'll want to continue letting [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) do this for you.

Comment: Hi, I kind of wanted it something like this. Using the new and delete keywords. https://imgur.com/a/4qLKxY1

Comment: @bob Why? That would be a worse solution.

Comment: The `vector` handles calling `new` and `delete` for you.  Let it do its job